# Spring serialization using @ResponseBody serializing setter methods as booleans

Tags: java, json, spring

I have some classes with Jaxb-generated child objects that when rendered by Spring's @ResponseBody serialization, render most if the child object json as expected, however it is also rendering some setter methods as if they themselves were fields, with primitive boolean values.

There isnt any special Json specific annotations on these objects, so they seem.like they should render normally.

Comment: Could you explain it more. Render what ? Please share the source as well.

Comment: I'll try to digest the library down to a few example classes